# My Links in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, quick-launch, links

How to configure the my links like quick launch whatever links are my favorite i need to configure in the quick links. Please help to to achieve this in SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Things have been changed in SharePoint 2013 for My Links as they were in SharePoint 2010.
You need to connect to office from the Ribbon to achieve the same.

[Please look into this post for details](http://sharepointconnoisseur.blogspot.in/2013/04/tips-for-add-to-my-links-function-on.html)

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it solves your query